# Mapping a class that consists only of a composite PK without @IdClass or @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I've got two tables `A` and `B` with simple PK's.

```
@Entity
public class A { 
    @Id
    public int idA;
}

@Entity
public class B { 
    @Id
    public int idB;
}
```

I want to map a new association class AB that simply stores the relations between `A` and `B`, with composite PK `idA`+`idB`. `AB` doesn't have any extra columns, just the relation between `idA` and `idB`.

Is it possible to map `AB` using a single class? I want to avoid having to create a new `ABId` class just to use it as `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` in `AB`, and I don't want to map this with a `@ManyToMany` association on `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to map such a join table? Just use a ManyToMany association between A and B. This join table will then be handled automatically when you'll add/remove a B to/from the list of Bs contained in A.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e11402

If you really want to do that, then just map the two IDs with the @Id notation. The primary class will be the entity class itself (which must be serializable), as explained in the [hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819). Note that this is Hibernate-specific.

Comment: I want to do this because I've already got `A` and `B` mapped, they are static data that is really unlikely to change (and with lots of other such unmapped relations). So is `AB`. I've got a list of `idA`'s retrieved at startup stored in a spring bean, and I'd like to just build a Map<idA, List<idB>> at startup. This table would avoid having to do joins or subqueries with `AB` at startup when recovering the list of `A`'s. I'll probably end up not mapping it with Hibernate and querying it with native SQL.

Comment: Great, that's just what I needed. I don't think it works on  `hibernate-annotations 3.3.1.GA` though, per [HHH-4327](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4327).

Comment: As expected, I just tested this, and the SQL query hibernate throws for `session.createCriteria(AB.class).list()` is this: `select this_.ID_A as COD2_248_0_ from AB this_`. All `idB` fields are null. I'll try updating to the latest version.

Comment: In a test with `hibernate-core 3.6.7.Final`, this worked as expected. I'm not upgrading, however. I'll stick to @IdClass with an inner static class.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if @JBNizet 's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793169/mapping-a-class-that-consists-only-of-a-composite-pk-without-idclass-or-embedd/7793396#7793396) worked. Unfortunately, there's an [old bug](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4327) which makes it impossible to adopt it in the version I'm using (3.3.1-GA)

I've finally sorted this out by defining an inner static ID class and using it as `@IdClass`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_AB")
@IdClass(value=ClassAB.ClassABId.class)
public class ClassAB implements Serializable {

    private String idA;
    private String idB;

    @Id
    public String getIdA(){ return idA; }
    public void setIdA(String idA){ this.idA = idA; }

    @Id
    public String getIdB(){ return idB; }
    public void setIdB(String idB){ this.idB = idB; }

    static class ClassABId implements Serializable {
        private String idA;
        private String idB;

        @Column(name="ID_A")
        public String getIdA(){ return idA; }
        public void setIdA(String idA){ this.idA = idA; }

        @Column(name="ID_B")
        public String getIdB(){ return idB; }
        public void setIdB(String idB){ this.idB = idB; }

        // HashCode(), equals()
    }
}
```

This way I don't have to define a new public class, and I don't have to modify the mappings file to include the ID class.